# How to bring google map markers above all the other markers when tapped?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm placing number of markers on the same latitude and longitudes with different color markers. When I tap the markers the infowindow for each marker is shown. But not the marker. Only the top most marker is visible even other marker is selected. I have tried to use `Z-Index`, but that's not working. Please tell a solution to bring the marker forward when selected.

```
for item in json {
    let jItem = item.1
    let lat = jItem["latitude"].doubleValue
    let lng = jItem["longitude"].doubleValue
    let mc = jItem["moisture"].doubleValue
    let sName = jItem["site_name"].stringValue

    let pos = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: lng)
    let marker = GMSMarker(position: pos)
    marker.title = sName

    if mc > 50 {
       marker.icon = UIImage(named: "red_icon")
    } else if mc < 50 {
       marker.icon = UIImage(named: "green_icon")
    }
}
```

This is the code. 
Please help me finish this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: i dont understand your question

Comment: think 2 markers in exact same latitude and longitude but has different marker icons. When we tap that only the topmost icon is visible. but the infowindow visible for both

Comment: what do you want to do?